# Robust library for PDF Rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, pdf.js

- Have been using raw `PDF.JS` to render PDF on client side(`AngularJS`) but have found some glitches like even though page is rendered according `PDF.JS`, on UI page renders slowly line-by-line which break other functionalities like navigating to some other page and is not good for product as a whole.
- Is there a robust library built over `PDF.JS` (I have came across other libraries like `ng-pdfviewer`, `angular-pdf-viewer` which I have not tried yet) which can be used to get the desired result or is there an another technology I could use.

Comment: An alternative library is e.g. http://pdfmake.org/ (with http://ngmodules.org/tags/ng-pdfmake for DI), but I haven't been using it myself.

Comment: pdfmake looks like if you want to generate a new pdf. I want something that renders an existing pdf. Found a new one : https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf. Will give it a look.

Comment: Why don't you use just an `iframe` to render it clientside?